# conditional column output for pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame looking like this:

```
nameA     statusA     nameB     statusB
a         Q           x         X
b         Q           y         X
c         X           z         Q
d         X           o         Q
e         Q           p         X
f         Q           r         Q
```

i want to print the rows of this dataframe based on the following rule: output column `nameA` if `statusA` is `Q` else if `statusB` is `Q` output column `nameB`. and in case `statusA` and `statusB` are both `Q`, both columns `nameA` and `nameB` should be output.

is there a oneliner for this?

**UPDATE:**

expected output:

```
a,Q
b,Q
z,Q
o,Q
e,Q
f,Q,r,Q
```

Comment: Do you want results from these two conditions to be printed saperately ?

Comment: Perhaps it would help to show the output you would like the code to produce?

Comment: question updated with expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
> data['con'] = data['statusA'] + data['statusB']
> data.apply(lambda v: v['nameA'] if v['con'] == 'QX' else v['nameB'] if v['con'] == 'XQ' else v['nameA']+ ','+ v['nameB'], axis=1)
0     a
1     b
2     z
3     o
4     e
5    f,r
dtype: object
```

You can use string concatenation for producing the exact result.

Some thing like

```
> data.apply(lambda v: v['nameA']+',Q' if v['con'] == 'QX' else v['nameB'] + ',Q' if v['con'] == 'XQ' else v['nameA']+ ',Q,' + v['nameB'] + ',Q', axis=1)
0        a,Q
1        b,Q
2        z,Q
3        o,Q
4        e,Q
5    f,Q,r,Q
dtype: object
```